# Play Framework trouble importing scala template from different package

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, twirl

Using Play 2.3.7, I have a set of bootstrap3 templates similar to this [example project](https://github.com/jamesward/play-example-form/tree/master/app/views), and they are in a package `app/views/bootstrap3/`. One of these bootstrap3 templates is a text field object in a file named `text.scala.html`. In a separate package, I have some other templates in which I want to use my custom text field. So, in package `app/views/other/` let's say I have I have a file `index.scala.html`, how do I correctly import my Bootstrap3 templates? This is what I have in my code

```
@import views.bootstrap3._

@* my bootstrap3 text field template *@
@text("some", "params", "here")
```

However, when I try to compile I get an error in `index.scala.html` (line 3) saying that

```
package scala.text is not a value
```

**How do I fix my code so that I can import my templates from a separate package?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates named `something.scala.html` get compile to a `views.{suffix}` package, where the suffix in this case is `html`, so for the *fully qualified* import you need to do:

```
@import views.html.boostrap3._

@text("some", "params", "here")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use import in the above case. you can just use

```
@bootstrap3.text()
```

in your in index.scala.html, it will import the partial template from bootstrap3/text.scala.html

Comment: This is correct but fragile: it will work when the template is compiled to the same package as the `bootstrap3` partials.

Comment: Agree, if you have multiple partials to be imported in the same package, you can globally import it. if not you can use the single line without importing it on top.