# Scalatags using play-bootstrap

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl, play-bootstrap

I'm replacing my twirl templates with ScalaTags code, and I ran into a problem. I'm using the [Play-Bootstrap](http://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/) library to easily write forms, however the import doesn't work outside of Twirl templates.

```
import b3.inline.fieldConstructor
```

I get the error:

```
not found: object b3
```

Any suggestions / solutions on how to keep using Play-Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522438/play-framework-trouble-importing-scala-template-from-different-package?rq=1) question.

```
import views.html.b3.inline.fieldConstructor
```

Comment: can you please remove the question now ? As it was not really a question.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh A more precise question would be "what's the general import for play-bootstrap?", but doesn't really matter, since the keywords are there already. Besides, stack overflow encourages people to even answer their own question immediately, in case people have the same problem. Could save someone 10 minutes.

Comment: Well... depend on your wish. I suggested to remove it because it will waste other people's time as the language, title and tags in question are all mis-leading. The questions has nothing to do with `scalatags` and `play-bootstrap`.